# How to test different values within an array

Tags: arrays, matlab, loops

I am trying to write a code in matlab that runs a total of 6 runs where each run tests 10 different values in the equation. So it should plug in a mumax = 0.48, Ksphe = 25, Ksglu = 50, Ksser = 175, and Ksthr = 100 and then test 10 different values of the Sphe, Sglu, Sser, and Sthr values in their ranges. Then it should move to the next Ks values and test 10 different S values.

I am a little lost on how to do this. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Code:

```
mumax = [0.48 0.47 0.51 0.49 0.49 0.43];
Sphe = linspace(40,60,10);
Sglu = linspace(85,115,10);
Sser = linspace(350,400,10);
Sthr = linspace(180,220,10);
Ksphe = [25 20 17 18 27 40];
Ksglu = [50 47 56 51 40 30];
Ksser = [175 150 200 22 175 120];
Ksthr = [100 80 120 90 110 100];

mu = mumax .* (Sphe./(Sphe+Ksphe)) .* (Sglu./(Sglu+Ksglu)) .* (Sser./(Sser+Ksser)) .* (Sthr./(Sthr+Ksthr))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
clc; clear; close all;
mumax = [0.48 0.47 0.51 0.49 0.49 0.43];
Sphe = linspace(40,60,10);
Sglu = linspace(85,115,10);
Sser = linspace(350,400,10);
Sthr = linspace(180,220,10);
Ksphe = [25 20 17 18 27 40]; 
Ksglu = [50 47 56 51 40 30];
Ksser = [175 150 200 22 175 120];  
Ksthr = [100 80 120 90 110 100]; 
% We create a meshgrid of the two type of arrays
% The mumax group will increase in the x direction and the Sphe group in the y 
% direction
[mumaxGrid,SpheGrid]=meshgrid(mumax,Sphe);
[KspheGrid,SgluGrid]=meshgrid(Ksphe,Sglu);
[KsgluGrid,SserGrid]=meshgrid(Ksglu,Sser);
[KsserGrid,SthrGrid]=meshgrid(Ksser,Sthr);
[KsthrGrid,SthrGrid]=meshgrid(Ksthr,Sthr);    

mu = mumaxGrid .* (SpheGrid./(SpheGrid+KspheGrid)) .* (SgluGrid./(SgluGrid+KsgluGrid)) .*...
(SserGrid./(SserGrid+KsserGrid)) .* (SthrGrid./(SthrGrid+KsthrGrid));
% mu is a 10 x 6 matrix.
```